# Is a linear map $T: V \to W$ possible given $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}\in V$ and $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}\in W$ are both linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Given linear map from $V$ to $W$:
>
> $T:\mathbb{R^4}\to\mathbb{R^4}$ and transformations:
>
> $T(\stackrel{v_1}{-1,5,2,3})=(\stackrel{w_1}{3,7,0,-3})$
>
> $T(\stackrel{v_2}{-1,1,0,1})=(\stackrel{w_2}{1,-1,2,1})$
>
> $T(\stackrel{v_3}{1,1,1,0})=(\stackrel{w_3}{2,3,1,-1})$
>
> give an example of the linear map if it exists.

After reducing the corresponding matrix for $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ we can that  see that $v_1$ is a linear combination of $\{v_2,v_3\}$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
v_3:&1&1&1&0\\
v_2:&-1&1&0&1\\
v_1:&-1&5&2&3
\end{pmatrix}\\
v_2\to v_2+v_3\\
v_1 \to v_1+v_3\\
\begin{pmatrix}
v_3:&1&1&1&0\\
v_2:&0&2&1&1\\
v_1:&0&6&3&3
\end{pmatrix}\\
v_1\to v_1 - 3v_2\\
\begin{pmatrix}
v_3:&1&1&1&0\\
v_2:&0&2&1&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Likewise after reducing the corresponding matrix for $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ we can that  see that $w_1$ is a linear combination of $\{w_2,w_3\}$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
w_2:&1&-1&2&1\\
w_1:&3&7&0&-3\\
w_3:&2&3&1&-1
\end{pmatrix}\\
w_1\to w_1 -3w_2\\
w_3\to w_3-2w_2\\
\begin{pmatrix}
w_2:&1&-1&2&1\\
w_1:&0&10&-6&-6\\
w_3:&0&5&-3&-3
\end{pmatrix}\\
w_1\to w_1-2w_3\\
\begin{pmatrix}
w_2:&1&-1&2&1\\
w_3:&0&5&-3&-3
\end{pmatrix}\\
$$

At this point (*) we know that $\{v_1,v_3\}$ and $\{w_2,w_3\}$ are linearly independent so we can add 2 more vectors $v_3=(0,0,1,0)$ and $v_4=(0,0,0,1)$ such that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is still independent. At this point I guess I could just make up any image for $\{v_3,v_4\}$ for example:
$$
T(v_3)=(1,2,3,4)\\
T(v_4)=(4,5,6,7)
$$

My **question** is at the point (*) I could proceed because the $dimSpan\{v_2,v_3\}=dimSpan\{w_2,w_3\}$ or there's another logic working in this case?

Comment: this is hard to read.  You have $\vec {v_1}=3\vec {v_2}+2\vec {v_3}$  But $\vec {w_1} \neq 3\vec {w_2}+2\vec {w_3}$, unless I have misread.

Comment: @lulu sorry I didn't realize the notation will be difficult so I changed it. So in order to a linear map to possible we need to have $w_1$ as exactly same linear combination as of $w_2,w_3$ as $v_1$ is of $v_2,v_3$?

Comment: Yes.  If there was a linear map $T$ then we'd have $T(\vec {v_1})=T(3\vec {v_2}+2\vec {v_3})=3T(\vec {v_2})+2T(\vec {v_3})\implies \vec {w_1}=3\vec {w_2}+2\vec {w_3}$

Comment: @lulu I'm trying to arrive to the same equation $v_1=3v_2+2v_3$ but I don't see how you get there. I see the elementary operation $v_1 \to v_1-3v2$ so this may explain $v_1=\mathbf{2v_2}+2v_3$ but how do you get the $2v_3$ part?

Comment: As I say, what you wrote is very hard to read and I might have misunderstood it.  You should not define your vectors inside the arguments of functions and you shouldn't write vectors without parentheses.    I read:  $\vec {v_1}=(-1,5,2,3),\,\vec  {v_2}=(-1,1,0,1),\,\vec {v_3}=(1,1,1,0)$.  Assuming I have this right, then $3\vec {v_2}=(-3,3,0,3)$ and $2\vec {v_3}=(2,2,2,0)$ and my claim is easily verified.

Comment: @lulu I reformatted the post.

Comment: Ok, but it still looks like what I wrote is correct, no?  Are you asking how I got it?  If so:  you said they were dependent, so I looked for a dependence, $\vec {v_1}=a\vec {v_2}+b\vec {v_3}$.  As the third coordinate of $\vec {v_2}$ is $0$ we must have $b=2$.  Similarly, looking at the fourth coordinate,  we must have $a=3$.  But I got this only looking at two coordinates so I need to check the first two.  If that failed, it would mean that the vectors were not dependent in this way.  But, as it happens, it checked out.

Comment: @lulu yes were right all along. I just edited the post to make it more legible. I understood how to get that $v_1=3v_2+2v_3$ I'd need to solve the linear equation $v_1=\alpha v_2+\beta v_3$. So in general in such questions I need to first check if $\{v_1..v_n\}$ are linearly dependent, then identify which vector is and then determine its linear combination. and then do the same with $\{w_1..w_n\}$?

Comment: That's one method. You could also use the definition of the map on the $\vec {v_i}$ to try to define it on a basis for the space they generate.  Once you have that you can ask whether the map you've produced satisfies all the properties you want, or just some of them.

Comment: @lulu in this case because I only have 2 linearly independent vectors I can add any other 2 vectors in order to extend to the basis of $\mathbb{R^4}$ as long as $\{v_1..v_4\}$ are still independent?

Comment: Not following.  Yes...if I give you independent vectors you can define a linear map just by telling me what it does to each of the vectors.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @lulu what I meant is that after row reducing $v_1,v_2,v_3$ I get only 2 linearly independent vectors ($(1,1,1,0)$ and $(0,2,1,1)$). But I'm in $\mathbb{R^4}$ so I need to 2 more vectors in order to form a basis. So I could choose $(0,0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,0,1)$ that way I'd get a basis.

Comment: But so what?  You would still have an inconsistent definition.  Suppose, in $\mathbb R^2$ I told you that $T(1,0)=(1,0)$ and $T(2,0)=(1,0)$.  Either $(1,0)$ or $(2,0)$ are a valid basis for the subspace on which $T$ is defined, but the definition of $T$ is simply not consistent (if you want $T$ to be linear).

Comment: @lulu so how would I use the method that you suggested in this case "You could also use the definition of the map on the $v_i$ to try to define it on a basis for the space they generate"?

Comment: Having selected a basis, I can define a linear map.  No obstruction there.  In the example I just gave, I could use $T(1,0)=(1,0)$ and define $T$ to be the identity map.  Absolutely no problem.  But then I must ask whether the function I just defined works or not.  That is, does it satisfy ALL of the assumptions or just the ones I like?    In this case, with $T=id$ we'd have $T(2,0)=(2,0)$ which contradicts the assumption, so the construction fails.